# Excel VBA - Remove text from left/right side of variable length string

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below VBA-code to make certain text between "!" characters bold (Example: !**example**!.).

Now I want to remove the "!" from the left and right side of the text. How can I manage to do that?

```
Sub change()
Dim r As Range, st As String, boo As Boolean
Dim L As Long, i As Long
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("Auswertung!A1:D100")

For Each r In rng.Cells

    st = r.Text
    boo = False
    L = Len(st)
    For i = 1 To L
        If Mid(st, i, 1) = "!" Then
            boo = Not boo
        Else
            If boo Then r.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True

        End If
    Next i
Next r 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you Split on the exclamation marks, you're automatically removing them. The text can be resurrected with Join and the array from the split allows multiple elements to be bolded.

By tackling each bold section as a whole and skipping over non-bold sections altogether, this should be substantially more efficient than 'walking' though the cell's content one character at a time.

```
Sub changeBold()
    Dim r As Range, rng As Range
    Dim tmp As Variant, i As Long, p As Long

    'Set rng = Application.Range("Auswertung!A1:D100")
    Set rng = Application.Range("sheet6!A2:A5")

    For Each r In rng.Cells

        p = 0
        tmp = Split(r.Text, "!")
        r = Join(tmp, vbNullString)

        For i = LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp) - 1 Step 2
            With r.Characters(p + Len(tmp(i)) + 1, Len(tmp(i + 1)))
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.Color = vbRed
            End With
            p = p + Len(tmp(i)) + Len(tmp(i + 1))
        Next i

    Next r

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

innerString = replace(fullString,"!","")

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Regular expressions -- in my opinion a very underused capability of VBA.

```
Dim r1 As New RegExp
Dim r2 As New RegExp
r1.Pattern = "^!"
r2.Pattern = "!$"

st = r1.Replace(st, "")
st = r2.Replace(st, "")
```

The `^` atom means "begins with" and the `$` atom means "ends with."

Alternatively you could extract the match between the exclamation points by using the regex capture `()` atoms:

```
Dim r As New RegExp
Dim m As MatchCollection
r.Pattern = "^!(.+)!$"

Set m = r.Execute(st)
If m.Count > 0 Then
  st = m.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(0)
End If
```

The big advantage of Regular expressions is you have the ability to not alter text inside of the characters.  For example, this would still work:

```
!I like Pie!  It's delicious!!
```

Regex support can be added to any VBA project by adding a reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5."